# Solve and Plot an example with boundary condition

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I have this piece of code to plot this solution, but I guess it should be numerical or parametric way!!!

```
 g[x_] = x Sqrt[(f/(x^(3 d))) - (a/(x^2)) + b  ];
 a=0.04;b=0.7;f=1-a-b;d=1;
 sol = DSolve[{g[x[t]] == x'[t],x[1]}==1, x[t], t]
 Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0.01, 10}]
```

Comment: Why did you delete your question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267184/plot-with-some-variables-parameters  as it had an answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: addressing the comment; plotting derivatives**

```
g[x_] = x Sqrt[(f/(x^(3 d))) - (a/(x^2)) + b];
a = 0.04; b = 0.7; f = 1 - a - b; d = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{g[x[t]] == x'[t], x[1] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0.01, 10}]
Plot[x'[t] /. sol, {t, 0.01, 10}]
Plot[(x'[t] /. sol)/(x[t] /. sol), {t, 0.01, 10}]
```

> [image: p1]
> [image: p2]
> [image: p3]

---

---

**Original answer**

Your mistake was with the curly brackets. The following works numerically

```
g[x_] = x Sqrt[(f/(x^(3 d))) - (a/(x^2)) + b];
a = 0.04; b = 0.7; f = 1 - a - b; d = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{g[x[t]] == x'[t], x[1] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0.01, 10}]
```

> [image: deplot]

If you try analytically

```
g[x_] = x Sqrt[(f/(x^(3 d))) - (a/(x^2)) + b];
a = 0.04; b = 0.7; f = 1 - a - b; d = 1;
sol = DSolve[{Rationalize[g[x[t]], 0] == x'[t], x[1] == 1}, x[t], t]
```

Mathematica has issues to `Solve` the following

> [image: sltn]

Comment: Thanks very much, Can I use this for Plot[{x'[t]/x[t] /. sol}, {t, 0.01, 10}]

Comment: @ArminSharafi done. Please have a look at the updated version of my answer. If I understood correctly, this is what you wanted